# efficient way to remove elements from list of ranges from a bigger range

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for an efficient way to remove a list of ranges from a bigger range.
The list of ranges will be contained with the bigger range

eg:

```
Bigger range: (0,10) 
List of Ranges:  [(2,7),(4,6),(6,8)]
expected result: {0,1,9,10}
```

I have an implementation below, but it is O(n2) and takes additional space of size O(n);

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/***
* input -> (0,10) and {(2,7),(4,6),{6,8}}
 * output -> {0,1,9,10}
 ***/
public class RemoveRanges {

    public static class Range {
        int start;
        int end;

        public Range(int x, int y){
            this.start = x;
            this.end = y;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Range outer = new Range(0,10);
        Range r1 = new Range(2,7);
        Range r2 = new Range(4,6);
        Range r3 = new Range(6,8);
        List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r1);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r2);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r3);

        System.out.println(removeRanges(outer, rangesToBeRemoved));

    }

    public static Set<Integer> removeRanges(Range outer, List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved ) {

        Set<Integer> outerElements = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = outer.start; i<=outer.end;i++ ){
            outerElements.add(i);
        }

        for (Range range : rangesToBeRemoved) {
            for (int j = range.start; j<=range.end; j++) {
                outerElements.remove(j);
            }
        }
        return outerElements;
    }
}
```

Comment: sort the ranges, then output using a loop over the outer range, skipping ranges.

Comment: @Bohemian can you elaborate plz?

Comment: @Bohemian the simple skipping is O(n^2) because you need to go through each item and check all the ranges

Comment: @Sergey no, you don't. My suggestion is O(n log n) where n is the number of *ranges*. It's O(n lon n) because you need to insertion sort the ranges. You could merge/reduce them on insertion for a modest performance gain.

Comment: Can you provide the (pseudo) code to demonstrate the idea then?

Comment: Why don't you create a hash map using all the numbers (the unrolled ranges) to be removed as the keys of the map and loop once over the bigger range, checking for the existence of the key in the hash map?

Comment: Think the best idea is to work with indexes instead of values. Please, see my answer for the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to @Bohemian idea by changing your method from "add all element then remove by range" to "add element out of remove range"

1. Sort the rangesToBeRemoved (by range.start)
2. Loop over the range and add element that are not cover by ranges
3. Add all element after the last range's end

   ```
   // assume rangesToBeRemoved has been sorted
   public static Set<Integer> addElementbyRemovedRanges(Range outer, List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved ) {

       Set<Integer> outerElements = new HashSet<Integer>();

       // this variable record the last element that has handled and act like a borderline
       int borderElementIndex = outer.start-1;
       for (Range range : rangesToBeRemoved) {
           if (range.end <= borderElementIndex ) {
               // omit this range as it has been cover by previous range(s)
               continue;
           }

           // add range if there is gap between range
           if (range.start > borderElementIndex ) {
               addElements(outerElements, borderElementIndex + 1, range.start - 1);
           }

           // update borderline
           borderElementIndex = range.end;
       }
       // Add all element after the last range's end
       addElements(outerElements, borderElementIndex + 1, outer.end);

       return outerElements;
   }

   public static void addElements(Set<Integer> outerElements, int start, int end) {
       if (start > end) {
           return;
       }
       for (int i=start; i<=end; i++){
           outerElements.add(i);
       }
   }
   ```

---

After sorting the rangesToBeRemoved, relationship between two ranges are

1. Completely in range (e.g. (2,7) and (4,6))
2. Partly in range (e.g. (2,7) and (6,8))
3. Not in range (e.g. (2,3) and (6,8) || (2,3) and (4,8))

For case 1, ignore the second range. For case 2, update the borderline to second range's end. For case 3, add the gap to element list and update the borderline to second range's end.

The above code is trying to compare virtual range (outer.start-1, borderElementIndex) and all ranges in rangesToBeRemoved (sorted)

Reuse your example: {(2,7),(4,6),(6,8)}.

- First, compare (-1,-1) with (2,7) and hit case 3, add the gap [0,1] into result set and change the borderElementIndex to 7.
- Next, compare (-1,7) with (4,6) and hit case 1, ignore it.
- Then, compare (-1,7) with (6,8) and hit case 2, change the borderElementIndex to 8.
- Finally, append remaining gap [9,10] into result set.

---

To further reduce space usage, you could use the same idea state in @Danny_ds solution to store the range of element instead of individual elements.

Comment: Can you calculate the complexity? As I see it's O(n*m). In case we work with indexes we could avoid inner loops which gives O(n). See my solution for details.

Comment: @SergeyProsin The complexity of above code is O(n+m) because it will loop all ranges once which result in O(m) and it will loop the outer element at most once in worst case which give O(n). Other than that, the sorting take O(mlogm).

Comment: in further improve the code, what are you doing at step 3? are you looping over bigger range? can you add code to what you mean?

Comment: does it mean, my solution above is also O(m+n) rather than O(n2) since I am touching each element only once.

Comment: @brainstorm your solution is O(m*n) in worst case if all your remove range is same as outer's range

Comment: @brainstorm update the solution and add an explanation

Comment: thanks for solution. you are calling addElements inside another for-loop. in worst case, this could be O(m*2) right?

Comment: @brainstorm No, the above code is O(m+n) in worst case and O(mlogm) for sorting. The method "addElements" never add same element twice due to variable "borderElementIndex".

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to stick to indexes instead of items values. The benefit is the operation of excluding one range is O(1) because instead of going through each item of the array we need to change one index value only.
After that, we should go through array indexes to compile the answer (see printRange method for details of how the result is to be constructed).
As for resulted complexity, the solution is **O(n) + O(m)** where **n** is the outer range size and **m** is the number of ranges we'd like to exlude. In terms of memory using the solution is O(n) because we need to use additional array to store indexes of n size.

Pre-conditions: all the ranges we'd like to exclude should be **sorted** by range.start values. In case they are unsorted it adds **O(m*log(m))** complexity to the algorithm.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;

/***
* input -> (0,10) and {(2,7),(4,6),{6,8}}
 * output -> {0,1,9,10}
 ***/
public class Main {

    public static class Range {
        int start;
        int end;

        public Range(int x, int y){
            this.start = x;
            this.end = y;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Range outer = new Range(0,10);
        Range r1 = new Range(2,7); //sorted ranges by range.start
        Range r2 = new Range(4,6);
        Range r3 = new Range(6,8);
        List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r1);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r2);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r3);


        printRange(outer, removeRanges(outer, rangesToBeRemoved));

    }

    public static void printRange(Range outer, int[] indexes)
    {
        int outerRangeSize = outer.end - outer.start + 2;
        int rangeShift = - (outer.start - 1);
        int current = 0;

        while (indexes[current] - rangeShift <= outer.end)
        {
            System.out.println(indexes[current] - rangeShift);
            current = indexes[current];
        }

    }

    public static int[] removeRanges(Range outer, List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved ) {
        int outerRangeSize = outer.end - outer.start + 2;
        int rangeShift = - (outer.start - 1);

        int[] outerElementsIndexes = new int[outerRangeSize];

        for (int i = 0; i<outerRangeSize;i++ ){
            outerElementsIndexes[i]=i+1; // construct indexes refereneces to the next indexes (one by one)
        }

        int currentIndex = 0; // point ot the first element in array
        int currentIndexNext = 1;

        for (Range range : rangesToBeRemoved) {
            if (currentIndex >= outerRangeSize) break;
            //int currentIndexNext = outerElementsIndexes[currentIndex];
            int nextIndexStart = range.start + rangeShift - 1; //calculate what index we should start from to exclude the range
            if (nextIndexStart < 0) nextIndexStart = 0;
            int nextIndexEnd = range.end + rangeShift + 1; // where we should jump to
            if (nextIndexEnd <= currentIndexNext) continue; // if we already skipped the range we're trying to exclude
            if (nextIndexStart <= currentIndexNext)
            {
              outerElementsIndexes[currentIndex] = nextIndexEnd; // case where we should extend the excluded range because it's intecepted with the last one we skipped

                currentIndexNext = nextIndexEnd;
            }
            else
            {
              outerElementsIndexes[nextIndexStart] = nextIndexEnd; // just exclude the range
              currentIndex = nextIndexStart;
              currentIndexNext = nextIndexEnd;
            }
        }
        return outerElementsIndexes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve your solution you could merge the list of intervals, which is a classic problem, you can find code there:
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/discuss/21222/A-simple-Java-solution

Then you can keep the same code but it becomes O(n) instead of O(n2), since all intervals are disjoint, each element appears at most in one input interval

As a second improvement you could just check if the current value is the left of an interval, if yes, skip that interval:

```
public static Set<Integer> removeRanges(Range outer, List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved ) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> Ranges = new HashMap<>();
    for (Range range : rangesToBeRemoved) {
        Ranges.put(range.start, range.end);
    }

    Set<Integer> outerElements = new HashSet<>();
    for (int j = range.start; j<=range.end; j++) {
       if(Ranges.get(j))
       {
           int left=j, right=Ranges.get(j);
           j += right - left + 1; //skip this interval
       }
       else
       {
           outerElements.add(j);
       }
    }

    return outerElements;
}
```

Comment: extra space with map?

Comment: yes though the map should be small as it contains only merged intervals

Answer (score 1):

While Bogemian's solution (comment) is probably the best (*"sort the ranges, then output using a loop over the outer range, skipping ranges"*), here's an additional way it can be done:

```
Bigger range: (0,10) 
List of Ranges:  [(2,7),(4,6),(6,8)]

Result list: [(0,10)]

to remove (2,7) split the result list: [(0,1),(8,10)]
(4,6) -> no action
(6,8) -> [(0,1),(9,10)]
```

This can be done without sorting the ranges, but then we have to look up the position in the result list each time.

Both solutions perform well with big ranges (if they return a list of ranges instead of a list with all the values).

For example:

```
Bigger range: (0,4000000000) // 4 billion in uint32
List of Ranges:  [(200,1000000),(1000000000,2000000000)]

Result list: [(0,199),(1000001,999999999),(2000000001,4000000000)]
```

The used space is minimal, execution instant. Using the above ranges with an algorithm that uses `O(n)` space, where `n` is the size of the outer range, would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the complexity of this, but thought it would be fun to solve using java-8:

```
Set<Integer> set = IntStream.concat(
            IntStream.range(outer.start, outer.end),
            rangesToBeRemoved.stream()
                    .reduce(
                            IntStream.empty(),
                            (stream, range) -> IntStream.concat(stream, IntStream.range(range.start, range.end)),
                            IntStream::concat)
                    .distinct())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> Boolean.TRUE, (x, y) -> null))
            .keySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post another answer to show the optimized solution which has O(1)+O(m) complexity where m - the number of ranges so it doesn't depend on the size of the outer range. However, it requires O(n) memory.

It also doesn't use any classes and should work blazing fast.

Happy to hear comments.

The code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;

/***
* input -> (0,10) and {(2,7),(4,6),{6,8}}
 * output -> {0,1,9,10}
 ***/
public class Main {

    public static class Range {
        int start;
        int end;

        public Range(int x, int y){
            this.start = x;
            this.end = y;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Range outer = new Range(0,10);
        Range r1 = new Range(2,7); //sorted ranges by range.start
        Range r2 = new Range(4,6);
        Range r3 = new Range(6,8);
        List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r1);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r2);
        rangesToBeRemoved.add(r3);


        printRange(outer, removeRanges(outer, rangesToBeRemoved));

    }

    public static void printRange(Range outer, int[] indexes)
    {
        int outerRangeSize = outer.end - outer.start + 2;
        int rangeShift = - (outer.start - 1);
        int current = 0;
        int currentNext = ((indexes[current] > 0) ? indexes[current] : current + 1);

        while (currentNext - rangeShift <= outer.end)
        {
            System.out.println(currentNext - rangeShift);
            current = currentNext;
            currentNext = ((indexes[current] > 0) ? indexes[current] : current + 1);
        }

    }

    public static int[] removeRanges(Range outer, List<Range> rangesToBeRemoved ) {
        int outerRangeSize = outer.end - outer.start + 2;
        int rangeShift = - (outer.start - 1);

        int[] outerElementsIndexes = new int[outerRangeSize];

        int currentIndex = 0; // point ot the first element in array
        int currentIndexNext = 1;

        for (Range range : rangesToBeRemoved) {
            if (currentIndex >= outerRangeSize) break;
            int nextIndexStart = range.start + rangeShift - 1; //calculate what index we should start from to exclude the range
            if (nextIndexStart < 0) nextIndexStart = 0;
            int nextIndexEnd = range.end + rangeShift + 1; // where we should jump to
            if (nextIndexEnd <= currentIndexNext) continue; // if we already skipped the range we're trying to exclude
            if (nextIndexStart <= currentIndexNext)
            {
              outerElementsIndexes[currentIndex] = nextIndexEnd; // case where we should extend the excluded range because it's intecepted with the last one we skipped

                currentIndexNext = nextIndexEnd;
            }
            else
            {
              outerElementsIndexes[nextIndexStart] = nextIndexEnd; // just exclude the range
              currentIndex = nextIndexStart;
              currentIndexNext = nextIndexEnd;
            }
        }
        return outerElementsIndexes;
    }
}
```